# Mong aggregation to directly return an array of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the following aggregation that get accounts by specific date

```
mongo.accounts.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            doc: "$$ROOT",
            month: {
                $month: "$created_at"
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: "$created_at"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "month": 6,
            "day": 26
        }
    }
]).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

It works just fine, but I don't like the format of data the query returns, currently this:

```
[{
    _id: 5d13cf6f4d0b262cafc415a4,
    doc: {
        _id: 5d13cf6f4d0b262cafc415a4,
        created_at: 2019-06-26T20:02:55.813Z
    },
    month: 6,
    day: 26
 }
 {
    _id: 5d793f8770bddb7d274efe62,
    doc: {
        _id: 5d793f8770bddb7d274efe62,
        created_at: 2019-06-26T18:40:07.031Z
    },
    month: 6,
    day: 26
}]
```

Is there a way to remove the redundant `_id` keys on the top-level as well as `month` and `day`? I am guessing this has something to do with `doc: "$$ROOT"`. The ideal response would be just the documents:

```
[{
    _id: 5d13cf6f4d0b262cafc415a4,
    created_at: 2019-06-26T20:02:55.813Z
},
{
    _id: 5d793f8770bddb7d274efe62,
    created_at: 2019-06-26T18:40:07.031Z 
}]
```

Comment: [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

Comment: The currently query response is right?

Comment: @DouglasEleuterio Updated the query response

Answer (score 0):

Like @Chridam suggested, we can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to make the sub-document `doc`, a root document. The following is the updated query:

```
mongo.accounts.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            doc: "$$ROOT",
            month: {
                $month: "$created_at"
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: "$created_at"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "month": 6,
            "day": 26
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            newRoot: "$doc"
        }
    }
]).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

We can further rewrite the query in the following way:

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $and:[
                    {
                        $eq:[
                            {
                                $month: "$created_at"
                            },
                            6
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $eq:[
                            {
                                $dayOfMonth: "$created_at"
                            },
                            26
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```